# How to set an object window scope from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, angularjs-scope

I have a requirement where I need to set an object into browser window scope using Angular controller.

For example, let say I have an object X which should only be instantiated once per window open, how can I use my AngularJS controller's $scope to set this object into browser window's context?

I came across $window object is available in AngularJS, but I need to understand if there is a provision of two-way binding in AngularJS for window based objects? For what I have learned, I can only access them, and not set them.

I am looking for a hack if there exists one.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you thought about using Local Storage, to store whatever it is that you need to?  With $window.localStorage you can set and get.

Comment: So the thing is I have to open a socket connection to my node server, and this object would be an active object, as it needs to stay connected to server at all times. Local storage would not work for my cause I guess.

Comment: This should be possible, sounds similar to what MeteorJS does with mongo and minimongo within the browser

Comment: Sounds like all you need is an angular service. Why would you need to create global object from inside angular scope?

Comment: @charlietfl:  Angular service is not serving my purpose, as every time it runs a digest cycle, it re-instantiates the socket connection, or every time I enter a new controller scope, it again re-instantiates the socket with a different socket id every time, which I don't want. I want that same socket object with the same socket id every time I call it.

Comment: @NickDelaney: I would appreciate if you could help me with small working example. Thanks a lot for the idea though! :)

Comment: A service is a singleton. The same connection should stay alive for the life of the page. Sounds like you are using it incorrectly

Comment: @charlietfl : I was using this sample provided below, please let me know if anything that I am doing wrong.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

Comment: @charlietfl : As it seems I was really doing something wrong. The thing is as soon as my controller was going out of scope and re-initialising, the socket would re-bind all listeners which were already bound, which I misunderstood for the re-initialising of socket, hence it was my mistake. Now I am removing all my listeners as soon as I go out of controller's context. Thanks for pointing me into right direction.